# ajax form not submitting handler expecting submit name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I'm having a little problem getting a form to submit via ajax. I think it's one of two problems:

1. leads.py (which I am able to view, but do not have the ability to modify) is expecting a submit input name of `name="submitButtonName"` and because I am using `e.preventDefault();` to disable normal form submitting the form is not being handled by the handler when submitted.
2. It could be possibly that the data being serialized is wrong, when i output it to console it looks like this which appears to be duplicated:

   first_name=Frank&last_name=TheTank&email_addr=frank%40thetank.com&remarks=&first_name=Frank&last_name=TheTank&email_addr=frank%40thetank.com

any suggestions?

here is the full script:

```
<!-- Defines element markup -->
<dom-module id="landing-modal">
<template>
    <div id="landing-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class=lead>
                To view this listing, please provide us with some basic contact information...
            </p>
            <form class="form-horizontal lead-form" method="post" action="/leads/buy">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Required Information</label>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" required="" class="style-scope lead-form">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" required="" class="style-scope lead-form">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="email" name="email_addr" value="" required="" class="style-scope lead-form">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="remarks" value="" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" class="btn">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submitButtonName" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
$(document).on('submit', '.lead-form', function(e) {
     $.ajax({
        url: $('.lead-form').attr('action'), //gets the action url
        type: $('.lead-form').attr('method'), //gets the form method post
        data: $('.lead-form').serialize(), //creates the form submit date eg. FirstName=Mickey&LastName=Mouse
        success: function(html) {
        console.log($('.lead-form').serialize());
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents the submit input from being submitted normally
});


Polymer({
        is: 'landing-modal',
        created: function() {},
        ready: function() {},
        attached: function() {},
        detached: function() {},
        attributeChanged: function(name, type) {}
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

edit::

I tried to add

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitButtonName" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

which results in a 500 error in console

server side code:

```
if "submitButtonName" in kwargs:
    errors = []
    if not kwargs['first_name']:
         errors.append("Please enter your first name.")
    if not kwargs['last_name']:
         errors.append("Please enter your last name.")
    if not kwargs['email_addr']:
         errors.append("Please enter your email address.")

    if errors:
         error_msg = "<ul>" + "".join([
              "<li>"+x for x in errors
         ]) + "</ul>"
         result['error_msg'] = error_msg
    else:
         save = True

if save:
    # 'remarks' is an invisible field that can only get filled in by
    # spam bots, so if there's a value in it, ignore the submission.
    if kwargs['remarks']:
         import sys
         sys.stderr.write("Ignoring spam submission: %r\n" % ([mode,kwargs],))
    else:
         self.save_form(mode, kwargs) 
    raise cherrypy.InternalRedirect("/leads/thankyou/"+mode)

result.update(self.form.render(values))
if mode=="C":
    result.update(self.cmaform.render(values))
if mode=="E":
    result.update(self.contactform.render(values))
return result
```

Comment: can you post the error message ?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: also example page http://disalle.dev.activemls.com/property/detail/5074813/landing

Comment: Exact error message is `The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
.`. By just seeing this people cannot help. so post your server side code and tag appropriately as this server code issue not Javascript

Comment: added the python code and tag

Comment: When you try adding the hidden input, give it a value: `<input type="hidden" name="submitButtonName" value="Submit" />`. Also, move the `console.log` line so it is just before the call to `$.ajax()`, And lastly, use `$(this)` to refer to the form within the submit-event handler.

Comment: @JohnS did all ove the above mentioned steps and all seems to be well in the world again.

Comment: I don't know python, but just try using `try` and `catch` blocks to catch the exception.

Comment: It was probably that you needed a value for the hidden input, but using `$(this)` is more efficient and is necessary if you have more than one form with the class "lead-form" on the page.